# Azure Data Factory to create an empty csv file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement where I want to check if file exist in a folder. If file exists then I want to skip else I want to create an empty csv file.
One way I have tried using Metadata activity and then using copy activity I am able to move empty file to the destination.
I want to check if there is any better way of creating empty csv file with on the fly without using copy activity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is another approach but it includes coding.

You can create a Azure Function in your preferred coding language and trigger it using Azure Data Factory `Azure Function` activity.

The Azure Function activity allows you to run Azure Functions in an Azure Data Factory or Synapse pipeline. To run an Azure Function, you must create a linked service connection. Then you can use the linked service with an activity that specifies the Azure Function that you plan to execute.

Learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity).

In Azure Function, you can access the directory where you want to check the files availability and can also create/delete/update the csv files with schema based.

Comment: thanks for answering. Currently I am following similar approach using Databricks notebook using Gen2 libraries. I am new to Datafactory that's why i wondered that is there any way to not put dependency on code to check it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Copy Activity. Source: Write a SQL Query in-line that includes all the columns as NULL and a WHERE clause that will produce no data.  Note that no tables are involved, and you can issue the query against any SQL source, including Serverless. Target: the csv file, include headers. Use an IF activity to create the file, if the metadata activity shows the file is absent.

Example query--

```
SELECT 
    CAST( NULL AS DATE) AS CreatedDate
    , CAST( NULL AS INT) AS EmployeeId
    , CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FirstName
    , CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR(50)) AS LastName
    , CAST( NULL AS CHAR(20)) AS PostalCode
WHERE
    1=2;
```

Comment: This works but feels like such a work around. The ability to just create a file should be a thing in Azure Data Factory.